# How to write a MDX query in SSAS for a calculated member using Case statement with Time Dimension

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, case, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have a calculated Member with this formula:

```
CASE
  WHEN SUM([Time].[Year].currentmember ,[Measures].[Amount]) > 0 
    THEN 0
  ELSE 1
END
```

This calculated member works as I wish but when I pull a dimension member like name even after passing the filter for year, when I pass this calcuated member it pulls data for all years.

For instance if I have data from 2000-2010 then when I pass filter as 2007, this member pulls data for all years showing blank values. Once I remove this calculated member then it works fine, it shows data only for 2007. I know am messing up in MDX, please help me thanks

Comment: Could you show the results of your queries, both the one that does what you want and the one that doesn't? I am not quite sure what problem you are trying to address. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot show it sorry,but I can explain

Comment: I cannot show it sorry,but I can explain if we have values for 2007  'dumbradish - 100' once I pull the calcuated member it becomes dumbradish - 100-1  (where 1 is the calculated member). Once I add the cacluated member it adds an additional row of data which does not belong to 2007 like 'Sampleuser - --1' but Sampleuser does not belong to 2007 thats why no data gets pulled too. I am saying like in my cube browser this calcuated member adds so many addiitional rows which dont belong to 2007 it basically adds all the names from all the years. hope this helped

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Presumably in your example, the values "dumbradish" and "sampleuser" belong to some other dimension. I think this is how I would expect your calcualted member to behave. If "sampleuser" has no records for 2007, your calculated member will return 1, as SSAS as a default will treat NULLS as zeroes. So your SUM will return NULL, treated as zero, and therefore your member returns 1. I guess you want it to return NULL, so it doesn't appear in your results. Create a member with just the SUM and not the CASE. Does that return "SampleUser" - 0?

Comment: When I remove the Case it works as I expect it does not pull in other values belonging to year except 2007. So how do i fix it for the Case statement or should I use something else. The calculated member is a measure and it does not belong to any dimension or associated measure group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you pretty much have the correct answer but you need to swap the `0` for `null` instead:

```
CASE
  WHEN SUM([Time].[Year].currentmember ,[Measures].[Amount]) > 0 THEN 1
  WHEN SUM([Time].[Year].currentmember ,[Measures].[Amount]) < 0 THEN 0
  ELSE   
    NULL  
END
```

Comment: This is not what I expect, if I do this then everything becomes 1 and it pulls values for years other than 2007. I dont want it to pull those values and the logic also breaks. I want it to show 1 when there is a value greater than 0 but now it becomes blank

Comment: @AdaPongada - what if you just swap the NULL and the 1 around?

Comment: That will still break my condition as I want it show 0 for negative values

Comment: your solution almost gives me the answer it does not pull names from other years but for negative values it shows as blank which is null but I want it to show zero

Comment: just expand the case then...I have edited so when >0 it is 1, when < 0 it is 0, and when 0 it is null.

Comment: I guess that should work am going to try it but just now I realized that I have this condition for aggregated values. So I am not getting the count. So in the auto generated count rows measure, is it possible to specify a condition where it will count only the rows which have positive value?. I can explain if am not very clear. Thanks a lot btw

Comment: @AdaPongada if you want to do Counts or Distinct Counts then you should really be aiming to use the mdx functions `Count` and `DistinctCount`

Comment: Using count or distinctcount will give me a count of rows what I want is if I have a column with 10 values, 3 negative and 7 positive then i want the count to be 7, how to go about to achieve this?